# Angular Material Stepper, Dynamic color change

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I am trying to use the angular material stepper to use as a progress tracker ( I know it's not meant for it... but that is the only one fitting my requirement). I have 5 steps in my stepper.

I want to turn the color on when the product or item has reached that point.
I found the class  `mat-step-icon-selected` for it. But it's not working.

I will be fetching the data from an API that would return me the status/step number.
and based on that I need to turn the color.

I am not able to change the color of the class. I tried using `ngClass` on `mat-step` 
But it's not working.

this is my code:

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true">

    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel >
          Initiated          
        </ng-template>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [className]="isTrue ? 'mat-step-icon-selected' : ''">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>PM</ng-template>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step #stepper>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>HM</ng-template>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>BU</ng-template>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>FT</ng-template>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Suggest a solution to update the color of the stepper displayed.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your component's css file:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-step-icon-selected {
    color: green; // your styles
}
```

To set the step dynamically, try like this:

.ts

```
import { MatStepper } from "@angular/material";

@ViewChild("stepper") private stepper: MatStepper;

selectStep(index) {
    this.stepper.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

.html

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
  ...
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: color is changing.. but only for the first one... I want it to work for other steppers as well

Comment: it should be something that i would be able to change the color of the specific step through a function call or an API response

Comment: Find the appropriate class and change style like this. I added this based on the class name you mentioned in your question

Comment: I want to add this specific class dynamically into a stepper

Comment: thats how it would be able to change color.... for a specific step

Comment: I am new to stackblitz let me try..btw...or else i'll add in questino itself

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular-material-stepper-ac84bt

Comment: You want to select a step dynamically?

Comment: Consider an order tracker... I want to change the color of the step based on the event... Hope you are able to picturize it?

Comment: It should be like a function is called which is changing the color of the stepper.

Comment: Like in the above link... only first step has the color....Based on the events further 2nd  3rd should chage the color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207177/discussion-between-abhigyan-nayak-and-adrita-sharma).